# Method of fundametal solutions (MFS) for nonhomogeneous PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I wonder what are the advantages of using the MPS-MFS (method of particular solution combined with method of fundamental solutions) for nonhomogeneous PDEs?

In order to implement MPS with radial basis functions (multiquadrics or compact supprt, doesn't matter) you still need to mesh the entire domain (like in FD) but, unlike FD, you eventually end up with either a fully-populated matrix (when using MQ) or something anyway denser than in FD (when using functions with compact support). So, if anything, the MPS-MFS must be more expensive than FD, not less.

The only advantage compared to FD or FEM seems to be that MPS-MFS is a meshless method in a sense that you don't need to build the connectivity matrix (which takes anyway just a fraction of the total time in a typical simulation job). Am I missing something?